# Is there a connection between Heavyweights and The Mighty Ducks?

Tags: d3-the-mighty-ducks, heavyweights

Many actors who starred in the 1995 film *Heavyweights* also starred in the *Mighty Ducks* trilogy.

Is there a connection between these two films?

Comment: I've re-phrased the question to ask whether a connection exists, rather than presupposing that there is one. If there is a connection, it can still be answered with an explanation of what the connection is, as per the original phrasing. Either way, this should prevent it from being closed as "needing details or clarity". If anyone thinks I've gone too far, feel free to rollback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short Answer:

The director and the casting director of a movie would usually have the most say in choosing actors, though the stars might have been chosen before the director and the casting director were hired.

Director Steven Brill and casting directors Lynda Gordon and Judy Taylor may have chosen actors from D2:the Mighty Ducks (1994) in Heavyweights (1995), and judy Taylor could have cast actors from Heavyweights (1995) in D3: The Mighty Ducks (1996).

Long Answer:

I checked the IMDB pages on those movies.

..............................................................................

The Mighty Ducks (1992) was:

Directed by:

Stephen Hereck

Written by:

Steven Brill.

Produced by:

Joe Avnet,
Martin Huberty,
Jordan Kerner,
Lynn M. MOrgan

Cast by:

Renee Rousselot

........................................................................

D2: The Mighty Ducks (1994 was:

Directed by:

Sam Weismann

Written by:

Steven Brill

Produced by

Jon Avnet,
Steven Brill,
Doug Claybourne,
Jordan Kerner,
Salli Newman

Cast by:

Lynda Gordon,
Judy Taylor

......................................................................................

Heavyweights (1995) was:

Directed by:

Steven Brill.

Written by:

Judd Aptow,
Steven Brill

Produced by:

Judd Apatow,
Roger Birnbaum,
Sarah Bowman,
Michael Fottrell,
Jack Giarraputo,
Joe Roth,
Charles J.D. Schlissel

Cast by;

Lynda Gordon,
Judy Taylor

..................................................................

D3: The Mighty Ducks (1996) was;

Directed by:

Robert Lieberman

Written by:

Steven Brill,
Kenneth Johnson,
Jim Burnstein

Produced by:

Jon Avnet,
Steven Brill,
C. Tad Devlin,
Jordan Kerner,
Kathy L. Menzies,
Elizabeth Guber Steven

Cast by:

Judy Taylor

.............................................

So the director of Heavyweights (1995) was Steven Brill, who had been the writer of The Mighty Ducks (1992) and D2: The Mighty Ducks (1994), and the co*producer of D2: The Mighty Ducks (1994).

The writers of Heavyweights (1995) were Steven Brill, who had been the writer of The Mighty Ducks (1992) and D2: The Mighty Ducks (1994), and the co*producer of D2: The Mighty Ducks (1994), and Judd Apatow.

Judd Apatow was also the executive producer of  Heavyweights (1995), but I have found no connection of him with the Mighty Ducks films.

The casting directors of Heavyweights (1995) were Lynda Gordon and Judy Taylor.  Judy Taylor went on to cast D3: The mighty Ducks (1996).  Thus actors from Heavyweights (1995) might have gone on to be cast in D3: The mighty Ducks (1996).

Lynda Gordon and Judy Taylor had previously been the casting directors for D2: The Mighty Ducks (1994) and may have cast many of the actors from that movie in Heavyweights (1995).  Many of the actors in D2: The Mighty Ducks (1994) were reprising their roles from The Mighty Ducks (1992) which had been cast by Renee Rousselot.

So director Steven Brill and casting directors Lynda Gordon and Judy Taylor may have chosen actors from D2:the Mighty Ducks (1994) in Heavyweights (1995), and judy Taylor could have cast actors from Heavyweights (1995) in D3: The Mighty Ducks (1996).

And if I wasn't too lazy I might have made an even longer answer checking the careers of all the actors in all four of those movies.